# React fullCalendar, reaching this.props in eventReceive function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, parameter-passing, react-props

I want to set one of my parent's attributes with my event's start time, but I cant reach this.props from inside the function(info) method. How could I reach tha method I want to use?

```
eventReceive={function (info) {
                this.props.onChangeStartDate(info.start);
              }}
```

onChangeStartDate is one of my parent's function which sets the starting date of an appointment in the parent component and I want to give the event's data which I just added in the calendar as a parameter to that function.

I got the following error:

> Cannot read property 'onChangeAppointment' of undefined

Thanks for your help.

Comment: change `function (info) {` to `(info) => {`, otherwise `this` will refer to the current function, not to the `this` that exists outside of that function

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, it looks like solves that problem, however now info.start returns undefined, but if I just type function(info){console.log(info.start)} it shows the date perfectly. What could be the problem?

Comment: not sure, see what's being passed in - do `console.log(info)` inside the function before `this.props.onChangeStartDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will solve your error.

```
eventReceive={(info) => {
    this.props.onChangeStartDate(info.start);
}}
```

Where
`() => {}` is an arrow function commonly used. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

The reason the error is occuring is because you losing the context of this inside the scope of the function.